# Customizing (not changing!) the VS 2008 start menu

Tags: visual-studio-2008, customization, start-page

Is it possible to customize the VS2008 start menu (remove the RSS feeds, expand recent programs, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Customizing the Visual Studio Start Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290347%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> You can customize the Start Page by
>   adding custom tabs with static or
>   dynamic content. Other types of
>   modifications to the Start Page are
>   possible, but remain unsupported by
>   Microsoft.

Go nuts.